# Cannot Restore from Backup File to Sybase

Tags: sybase, restore, sap-ase

We have a very old sybase server. Our database in it is acting up.  We need to restore the backup database file from our backup sybase server.  But when I try that, I keep getting this error message:

> Msg 7205, Level 17, State 2: Line 1: Can't open a connection to site
>   'SYB_BACKUP'.  See the error log file in the SQL Server boot
>   directory.

That is how I restore the database backup:
1.  Use RCP to copy the dump file from the spare server to the primary server. And name the copy "frombkup_mydb.dump".
2.  Drop the old database from the primary server, and re-create an empty one.
3.  Then use the following command to load the database from the backup dump file:

load database mydb from "/export/home/syb11.dump/frombkup_mydb.dump"

Unfortunately I don't know where the error log file is.  I am not familiar with SCO Unix and Sybase.

Does anyone know why the restore doesn't work?

Please help.  Thanks.

Jay Chan

Comment: This is probably more appropriate for the [dba stack](http://dba.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Also, you say Old - but it's more helpful to get an actual version.  This can be done by issuing `select @@version` in the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's likely that your Backup Server is not running.

The SAP/Sybase ASE database process requires the backup server to be running for database backups or restores.

To find which database processes are running you can use the `showserver` command usually located in:

```
$SYBASE/$SYBASE_ASE/install/showserver
```

If the backup server is not running (likely), then in the ./install/ directory, look for the file named `RUN_SYB_BACKUP`

You can start the server by issuing the command (from the ./install/ directory)

```
startserver -f RUN_SYB_BACKUP
```

This should start the backup server, and allow you to restore the database.

Comment: Your suggestion works!  Thanks for your help.  Normally when I reboot that server, I will always run RUN_SYB_BACKUP and showserver.  May be I was doing many things in that server at that time trying to fix some other problems and that might have turned off the backup server.  I am glad that I get past this error.  I have another error; but that is a different story.  Unfortunately I don't have enough credit to "vote up" your answer.  Otherwise, I would have done this.  Hopefully someone else can vote-up your answer.  Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Glad to help. Don't forget to accept the answer as correct. That's even better than an up vote. :)

Comment: Done.  I have checked mark your message as the answer of my question.  Thanks again for your help.  I appreciate that.